# Create multidimensional array from serialized array posted with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have a list with three things, first a title for the entire list, then a user can add categories with questions below each category dynamically.

I need to add these lists to my database and currently have this array when posting (using ajax with `serializeArray` ):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => lijsttitle
            [value] => Title
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => category[]
            [value] => category 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => question[]
            [value] => question 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => question[]
            [value] => question 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => question[]
            [value] => question 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => category[]
            [value] => category 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => question[]
            [value] => question 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => question[]
            [value] => question 2
        )

)
```

All questions and categories are already in the correct order but I want them grouped together, something like this:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [value] => Title
        )

    [category 1] => Array
        (
            [question] => question 1
            [question] => question 2
            [question] => question 3
        )

    [category 2] => Array
        (
            [question] => question 1
            [question] => question 2
        )
)
```

Or maybe another way if there is a better one.

I serialize my form like this:

```
$( ".lijstbutton" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  url = 'includes/createlist.php';

  $lijst = $( '#lijstform' ).serializeArray();

  var posting = $.post(url, {lijst: $lijst});

    posting.done(function( data ) {
     $( ".lijstresult" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( data );
   });
  });
```

And to show my current array I have this code in createlist.php :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST['lijst']);
echo '</pre>';
```

In the end I need all questions linked to a category and all categories linked to the title of the entire list.

So you can have multiple lists each with their categories and questions below those categories.

Comment: And have you tried to write any code to re-organise this array?

Comment: How do you decide the categories of questions? You don't have a key value pair which can provide details about the category of a question.

Comment: @BhaumikMehta I know, how can I do that? I read you have to add `[]` after the name of the input fields, but in my array there is nothing added, just the empty `[]`

Comment: Could you show us the JSON?

Comment: @Keith I don't think it is JSON, but when I encode it this is what you see: `[{"name":"lijsttitle","value":"sdg"},{"name":"category[]","value":"dsg"},{"name":"question[]","value":"dsgsd"},{"name":"category[]","value":"gsdgsd"},{"name":"question[]","value":"gsd"}]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rearrange the data a bit. You can't user `'question'` as a key multiple times in an `array`. `$arr` is the POSTed data.

```
$store = [];

// pull off first arr element
$title = array_shift($arr);
// save title to store
$store['title'] = $title['name'];

$currCat = '';
foreach($arr as $a) {
  $val = $a['value'];
  // handle category
  if($a['name'] == 'category[]') {
    // save cat name
    $currCat = $val;
    // init questions array
    $store[$currCat] = [];
  }
  else {
    // add question to question array
    $store[$currCat][] = $val;
  }
}

print_r($store);
```

Comment: I get an Internal Server Error 500 from above code. Since the response is used with Ajax I can't see the exact PHP error.

Comment: Edited. Had a few typos.